# How to convert mp4 to NSData?

Tags: ios, video, nsdata

[image]I have file in XCode with name vvideo.mp4. I am trying to convert it to NSData like below

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"vvideo.mp4" options:nil error:nil];
```

But as I log data, it returns null.

What is right way to convert any video to NSData?

File is added and copies properly in Xcode, you can see here.

EDITED QUESTION....

Comment: That's the right way. Your file must just not be named like this, or you haven't included it in your project. I mean, this creates a NSData with the contents of the file, loaded in memory. So that's *also* the right way to bring your device to its knees by loading a whole movie in RAM.

Comment: edited the Question, check it

Comment: Its of few seconds, only 10 seconds video sir....

Answer (score 8):

`dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` takes a file path and not file name. If the video file is in application bundle you should do,

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vvideo" ofType:@"mp4"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:nil error:&error];
if(data == nil && error!=nil) {
    //Print error description
}
```

Rather than passing `error` argument as `nil` pass the value, it will be useful in understanding error condition, if any occurs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: 2013-10-24 17:09:56.793 GascoLiveStream[17380:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument'

Comment: @Duaan Print `filePath` and check if it correct, pass `error` argument and check what is the error.

Comment: options:nil  here is the issue and warning daer

Comment: @Duaan What is the warning? You can pass it as `NSDataReadingUncached`.

Comment: @Duaan Check my edit, pass `NSError` argument. Print it and check what is the error. Let me know as well.

Comment: -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:]: nil file argument'

Comment: It does not go inside If body, as it crashes there.

Comment: @Duaan What is the file path? Can you tell me?

Comment: I simply add this to Supported Files.

Comment: dear, as I use dataWithContentsOfURL and pass URL, it works, but locally it is not converting any video

Comment: @Duaan You have still not told me what I asked you. Did you print `filePath`? What does it show? `nil` file argument means the file does not exist at the location you are reading it from.

Comment: Dear sorry for late @Amar, its null. Now I will try to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can do this in Swift 5:**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "download", ofType: "mp4"),
   let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
      // Use this data
}
```

**Very important** thing to note here is that the file has to be somewhere inside the project instead of Assets.xcassets otherwise path would be `nil`.

Also make sure to associate the correct Target Membership for example:

[image]

[image]