# How to get NSData from file by using PHAsset

Tags: ios, file, nsurl, phasset

I have file at path

```
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0197.mov
```

But when I try this code-

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:assetUrl.relativePath options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];
```

I got nothing but error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "Не удалось завершить
>   операцию. (Cocoa, ошибка 257)" UserInfo=0x175a61380
>   {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0197.mov,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x17424e550 "Не удалось завершить операцию.
>   Operation not permitted"}

File exists but I can't read it.

But at the same time AVPlayer normally plays video file.

I tried

```
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetUrl] options:nil];
```

But I did not get any result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't access the `NSURL` directly as the files are outside of the sandbox of your app. Some frameworks (like `AVPlayer`) have exception entitlements and can access the URLs.
To access the data of `PHAsset` objects take a look at the following methods of `PHImageManager`:

For images: `requestImageDataForAsset`

For videos: `requestExportSessionForVideo`

Answer (score 4):

For me helped the following code. It's important to use `relativePath` instead of `absoluteString`.

```
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:videoContent options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset* avasset, AVAudioMix* audioMix, NSDictionary* info){
                AVURLAsset* myAsset = (AVURLAsset*)avasset;
                NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myAsset.URL.relativePath];       
                if (data) {
                }
    }];
```

Swift 3 version:-

```
PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (asset, mix, nil) in
                    let myAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset
                    do {
                        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: (myAsset?.url)!)
                        self.selectedVideoData = videoData  //Set video data to nil in case of video
                        print("video data : \(videoData)")

                    } catch  {
                        print("exception catch at block - while uploading video")
                    }
                })
```