# getting error when i trying to convert AVAssetURL to Data

Tags: ios, swift, avasset

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_9807.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/109APPLE/IMG_9807.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c1e5fe00 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"

i am sending asset URL to other controller and try to convert into data

```
PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: self.albumView.phAsset, options: options) { (video, audioMix, info) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     let urlAsset = video as! AVURLAsset
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                        self.delegate?.fusumaVideoCompleted(withFileURL: urlAsset.url)
                    })
                }
            }
```

here below methods for convert AVAssetUrl to data

```
 do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: product.videoURL, options: .mappedIfSafe)
                return .upload(.multipart([MultipartFormData(provider: .data(data), name: "post[video]", fileName: "video.\(pathExtension)", mimeType: "video/\(pathExtension)")]))
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error)
            }
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652094/how-to-get-nsdata-from-file-by-using-phasset, which tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error tells you, you cannot access the video file in the user's photo library by way of its URL for purposes of uploading it. You should obtain the video data and upload that. A video is very big, so you should not get the data directly and hold it in memory; instead, export the data to a file in a place that you *are* allowed to access, such as the Temporary folder.

To do that, you might (for example) use this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phassetresourcemanager/1616280-writedata

Or this one:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616981-requestexportsession

If you use the Mail app to email a video from your own device's photo library, you will actually see that happening; there is a pause with a progress bar while the video is exported, and *then* the email is constructed.